# Collection extension not visible when called within same extension?

Tags: swift

I am using the following extension on Collection:

```
extension Collection where Indices.Iterator.Element == Index {

    subscript (safe index: Index) -> Generator.Element? {
        return indices.contains(index) ? self[index] : nil
    }

}
```

I want to then use it in a function found in another Collection extension like this:

```
extension Collection {

    func tesFunc() -> String? {

        let s = [safe:1]

        return nil
    }
}
```

I am not able to make this work. The error I get is:
"Use of unresolved identifier 'safe'

How can use the save subscript in the function found on the second extension on Collection?

[image: Error as shown in a Playground]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great question. My initial answer was totally wrong and you *can* do this.

The problem is that you've constrained the initial `Collection` extension with `where Indices.Iterator.Element == Index` but the second extension is unconstrained.  You have to apply the same constraints to both.  This is ok:

```
extension Collection where Indices.Iterator.Element == Index {
    subscript (safe index: Index) -> Generator.Element? {
        return indices.contains(index) ? self[index] : nil
    }
}

extension Collection where Indices.Iterator.Element == Index {
    func testFunc(index: Index) -> String? {
        let _ = self[safe: index]
        return nil
    }
}


let a = [1,2,3,4,5]

a[safe: 0] // 1
a[safe: 7] // nil
```

Note in my `testFunc()` the use of `self` in `self[safe: index]`. That's mandatory.  Otherwise the compiler thinks you're trying to create a dictionary with a key of `safe` and it can't resolve `safe`.